# Why isn't my backtracking solution for N queens problem working?

Tags: c++, backtracking, n-queens

Here's the output that it returns when I call it from the main function by passing args: 0 and board where 0 is the row number to start from and board is a 4x4 board filled with zeros:

```
9       1       1       1
1       1       9       1
1       1       1       1
1       0       1       1
```

Note: 9 means a queen and 1 means a cell attacked by a queen, 0 is a safe cell which neither has a queen on it nor is attacked by a queen.

```
bool queen_placer(int row, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &board)
{
    if (row == board.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < board[0].size(); col++)
    {
        bool safe = is_valid(row, col, board); //is_valid returns true if the position doesn't contain any queen and is not attacked by any queen
        if (safe)
        {
            board[row][col] = 9;
            value_assigner(row, col, board); //value assigner just assigns the attack values of the queen so placed
            if (queen_placer(row++, board))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any backtracking. Incrementing `row` also looks odd, both in the incrementation itself and in the passing of the same row again  to the recursion.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried to implement backtracking but perhaps I failed. Could you kindly help me out by pointing out my mistake and correcting it?

Comment: Backtracking involves undoing a choice that leads to failure, but you stick to `board[row][col] = 9;` regardless of what happens.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake. I edited the code to create a board_prev save state before I placed the queen and reverted the board to the board_prev state if the recursive call doesn't return true. And the code is returning the correct solution now. I don't know about Stack Overflow code of conduct because I'm new to it. Should I update my question to say that it is solved and edit the code?

Comment: The normal procedure is that I convert my comment to an answer, which you accept.

Comment: @molbdnilo Also: I know there are two solutions for this problem on a 4x4 board but mine returns only one. How do I make it so that it returns all the solutions or maybe even store all the solutions in a container?

Comment: @molbdnilo Sure! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dharman Oh okay, I  didn't know you weren't supposed to do that here. I thought others who might run into a similar problem might be helped if I let them know that the solution has been found but it completely escaped me that I could also post it as an answer instead of polluting the original question. Thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not backtracking - backtracking involves undoing a choice that leads to failure, but your `board[row][col]` is forever.

You need to restore the board to its previous state if the recursion fails.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the correct code which solves this problem with changes made to the original code only on lines 9 and 21:

```
bool queen_placer(int row, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &board)
{
    if (row == board.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < board[0].size(); col++)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> board_prev = board; //Added line
        bool safe = is_valid(row, col, board); //is_valid returns true if the position doesn't contain any queen and is not attacked by any queen
        if (safe)
        {
            board[row][col] = 9;
            value_assigner(row, col, board); //value assigner just assigns the attack values of the queen so placed
            if (queen_placer(row + 1, board))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                board = board_prev; //Added line
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's the output that this code gives:

```
1       9       1       1
1       1       1       9
9       1       1       1
1       1       9       1
```